# Configured provider not recognized inside module

Tags: terraform

I am working on a Terraform configuration for a new project. The project consists of multiple microservices for which I've written modules. The project is supposed to be hosted on Digitalocean, so I installed the [Terraform DigitalOcean Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/2.3.0) as a required provider:

```
# ./versions.tf
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14"
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = "2.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

which is then 'initialized' in `./main.tf`:

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = var.do_token
}
```

However, when I try to run `terraform init` it fails because of error `Error: Failed to query available provider packages.`

`terraform providers` reveals that this happens because a module tries to require provider `hashicorp/digitalocean` instead of `digitalocean/digitalocean`:

```
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/digitalocean/digitalocean] 2.3.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 1.13.3
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes-alpha] 0.2.1
└── module.spaces
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/digitalocean]
```

I have tried to pass a the provider through the `providers` option in the `module`, but that didn't seem to make a difference:

```
module "spaces" {
  source     = "./Spaces"
  providers = {
    digitalocean = digitalocean
  }
}
```

Is this a bug within Terraform 0.14 perhaps, or am I just misunderstanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this ‘registry.terraform.io/digitalocean/digitalocean’ instead of ‘digitalocean/digitalocean’...

Answer (score 0):

It's failing when it's used in a submodule because you only have the `required_providers` configuration at the top level, you  need to add it in each module.

This is explained in detail in [this thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25172)

> The provider source needs to be declared in each module because an
> interesting side effect of the provider source work is that we can now
> use multiple providers with the same name in configuration. Each
> module could use a provider named 'dns' with a different source.
> Internally, terraform uses the source to create a FQN (fully-qualified
> name) for each provider, so you could have for example three modules,
> each using one of "mildwonkey/dns" "hashicorp/dns" and "yourname/dns".